# MySQL how to create string with multiple parameters

Tags: mysql

I have a line "X1:{} X2:{} X3:{} X4:{} PERFECT"

And I have a table test1 for example

```
A | B | C | D
5   6   7   8
```

how I can create a table test2:

```
ID | VALUE
 1    X1:{5} X2:{6} X3:{7} X4:{8} PERFECT-> value - it is string in one column
```

Please, help.

Comment: Nested REPLACE()

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: CREATE TABLE NEWTABLENAME
SELECT * FROM OTHERSTABLE;

If i under stand you right, you want to make a table similar to the first one, or forgive me if I misread it, but this code first line creates the table, the second line selects the format and data from the existing table to use that for the new table.

Comment: One thing I would HIGHLY suggest, is if you are in a Microsoft Environment, and can install and thus use MS Workbench, it can help you create tables and modify existing using a GUI and it's free.  If you are unfortunate enough to be stuck with Unix/Linix phpAdmin can do some things too for you like this.

Comment: Probably something like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb790085368ba9be6d13bc3d3f5dfb67

Comment: Yea. It is the answer. Thank you.